# Css list in a list with absolute position width issue

Tags: css, list, internet-explorer-7, absolute

hi i'm making a dropdown menu, but there is a problem with ie7, sub-list's 1. item is good but others width is like 10px, here is example;
http://jsfiddle.net/YGF7t/

there is a solution for this? or What's my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzWcy/

i took `clear:both;` out of your last style

Comment: Yea that works, i put clear:both; to ul instead of li thanks.